# Simulate keypress in a Linux C console application

Tags: c, linux, x11, keypress

Is there any way to simulate a keypress in Linux using C?

In my specific situation, I'm on Ubuntu 9.04 and need a simple app that invokes a press on the "pause" button when launched. That would get an iframe in Firefox to refresh using Javascript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you mean the "X11 application" - it is not entirely clear from your description what you are planning to do. The below code snippet will send the "pause" keycode to the application that currently has the keyboard input focus under X11 using XTest extension - from what I've read this is the most compatible way to "fake" the keyboard events. See if you might apply this to your scenario (no error check on whether the XOpenDisplay succeeded, to make it simpler).

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
...
Display *display;
unsigned int keycode;
display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
...
keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_Pause);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, False, 0);
XFlush(display);
```

You will need to link with the -lX11 -lXtst.

Obviously the firefox would need to have focus at that time.

However, I would be curious to know what is the bigger task that you are trying to accomplish - I suspect there should be a more elegant solution than spoofing the keypress events.

Comment: side comment about my own use case for the above code: I had it an OpenCV-powered weekend hack that allowed me to fake the arrow keypresses by moving my head in front of webcam (so I could scroll the /. posts and eat sandwich at the same time :-)

Comment: I want to use a griffin powermate to reload an iframe :)

Comment: Ah, so it's pretty much the same usage as my case :)

Answer (score 7):

There's a programmable library called 'xdotool':

> sudo apt-get install libxdo-dev libxdo2
>
> cat test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xdo.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    xdo_t * x = xdo_new(":0.0");

    while(1) {
        printf("simulating Shift_L keypress\n");
        xdo_keysequence(x, CURRENTWINDOW, "Shift_L", 0);
        sleep(5);
    }

        return 0; 
}
```

Run like this:

> gcc test.c -lxdo -o test

Comment: Do you have the link for the documentation? I can't find anything for the programmatical part of xdotool.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam There is no good documentation for this library.  The only exmaples seem to use `CURRENTWINDOW` and none show how to search for a window.  I mean the documentation that is available is horribly incomplete.  eq. `max_depth - depth of search. 1 means only toplevel windows`.  Uh-huh, and what are the other values?  Why do we see people using `-1`?  How would they even know what it does or that it even exists?  It's sad that so much work has gone into this library, just to have people waste their time searching for non-existent/horribly incomplete documentation.

Comment: @Deanie This is a big problem in the entirety of C and C++ to be honest.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam without proper documentation, how could you ever know this?  C has been around from the 70's and the documentation makes it usable, still.  This is just showing the true laziness of certain programmers.  Those that can program do, those that can't, have problems with documenting.  `libxdo` had such potential, I guess I'm just disappointed in the creators inability to know that documentation is just as important as the code!

Comment: @Deanie At times, you have to do a certain work and you have to use a certain library. There's no way to manoeuvre around it, and then you get hit with lack of documentation. That's it! One piece in the ecosystem is undocumented, everything falls down. This can also lead to problems in dependencies.

Comment: This is the right direction but here is ```xdo_send_keysequence_window``` and with ```+``` : ```xdo_send_keysequence_window(x, CURRENTWINDOW, "Ctrl+Alt+D", 0);```