# Firing an Play/Pause event in Linux

Tags: c, linux, events, shell, media

I would like to fire a Play/Pause event with a shell script or a C program on a Linux machine.
Unfortunately i haven't found a way to do this yet. 
At first I thought of simulating a click on the fn-Play key, but I couldn't find a way to make that work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to play/pause? Is it some specific program that you want to control?

Comment: I would like to fire a global event, which is received by every running multimedia program like rhythmbox or xbmc. Just like pressing a button on a remote.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo showkey -k
```

This will show you the corresponding keycode when you press on <kbd>Fn + F6</kbd>. Assuming the play button is on <kbd>F6</kbd>. You can then [simulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262310/simulate-keypress-in-a-linux-c-console-application) the appropriate keypress in C.