# How do i get my c++ program to "press keys" on its own?

Tags: c++, linux

Im writing a little C++ progam but got to a point from which on i could not go on:
I want my program to control an external program using a certain combination of keys.
Yes, this sounds like a horribly unclean workaround, but thats what i want to do ;)

To be more specific:
I want my little C++ program to control the already running program elinks (a text based internet browser) by pressing the "esc" then "v" and then "h" -keys (this is used to toggle between html and plain text output in elinks).

But unfortunately, I do not know how to get a C++ program to type a certain combination of keys (...if this is possible at all).
I already tried the search function but wasnt able to find a solution.
It would be very kind of you, if someone could give me a hint on what to do here.

Thanks,
Spoekenkieker

P.S.: Im running Linux

Comment: This is platform-dependent. Are you running on Windows? Linux?

Comment: Linux. Question edited ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate keypress in a Linux C console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262310/simulate-keypress-in-a-linux-c-console-application)

Comment: @Axalo : Thanks. I did not find this question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over how to start the `elinks` browser, you can start it under the GNU `screen` terminal multiplexer and use its `stuff` command to send key inputs:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen

This way you're not required to learn the complications of X Windows programming.

Comment: I just figured out how to do it with the X Windows programming but i will try your way to. This one seams to be cleaner :D