# Emulate a global keypress in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, keypress

I am building a Qt Application for a raspberry pi, which is connected to a rotary encoder. When the user presses the rotary encoder button, the application registers the hardware interrupt from the button and emits a signal which the application can intercept.

The challenge is that the application has multiple windows that can be displayed, and I would like to simply have a function which translates the button press signal into a global key press that can be registered by any active window in the application, without having to add extra logic to determine which window is active to send the key press directly to it. Is there a way to simulate a system-wide key press so that whatever window is in focus will get it?

So far, I have the following snippet of code, though it requires a reference to a specific QObject to direct the keypress to:

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (receiver, event);
```

where `receiver` is the object to direct the keypress too. Any ideas?

Comment: The `QCoreApplication::postEvent()` method only sends the events to the GUI elements, it does not send it to the OS or other applications. I recommend using the libraries of the OS that surely allows you to emulate global keys.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262310/simulate-keypress-in-a-linux-c-console-application

Comment: Is it possible to at least trigger the key events so that all forms and controls in the application can get it (or even just the active form)? I'm trying to avoid adding signals and slots to each individual view controller to handle the keypresses

Comment: If you want to send the event to the widget that has the focus then use `QApplication::focusWidget()`, I recommend delimiting your problem since depending on what you want you can have different solutions, I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To broadcast a key event to **all** top-level widgets (i.e. windows):

```
    for(auto w : qApp->allWidgets())
    {
        if(w->isTopLevel())
        {
            qApp->postEvent(w, new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier));
        }
    }
```

To directly send the event to the active window (the foremost one):

```
qApp->postEvent(qApp->activeWindow(), new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier));
```