# how to trigger capslock from code in gnuforth on linux host

Tags: assembly, keyboard, abi, forth, gforth

how to trigger caps lock from code in gnu-forth ?
currently as a temporary solution I use

```
: caps s" xdotool key Caps_Lock" system ;
```

I'm looking for either a full gforth code solution either a abi-code assembly solution

I also tried many solutions around external nasm code but xdotool is available, so I preferred using it.

I tried  many thing around https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/386-Assembler.html#g_t386-Assembler documentation without result until now.

like

```
abi-code toto                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
0x3A .b al mov                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x02 .b ah mov                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x80 int                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ret                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
end-code
```

and so on ... without results

```
I near solution I think I also tryied to work around asm code below 
  ; Open /dev/port for I/O operations
  mov eax, 5        ; syscall number for sys_open
  mov ebx, dev_port ; pointer to the filename "/dev/port"
  mov ecx, 2        ; O_RDWR mode
  int 0x80          ; Call the kernel

  ; Enable Caps Lock by sending the scancode to the keyboard controller
  mov dx, 0x60      ; Port 0x60 is the keyboard controller data port
  mov al, [capslock_scancode]
  out dx, al
```

so how to trigger ON caps-lock from the gnuforth code ?

Comment: Basically, this question isn't about Forth, but about Linux and a windowing system API (I would suggest to add the corresponding tags).  See also: [Simulate keypress in a Linux C console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262310/simulate-keypress-in-a-linux-c-console-application), [How to simulate a key press in C++ for Linux](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/how-to-simulate-a-key-press-in-c-for-linux.2562684/).

Comment: no its is forth oriented // i really not want an external solution but o forth one like insider asm abi-code or a pure forth one //  the fact about linux is only the platform nothing to see about C solutions and so on this is out of interest at all  here (and optionally stackoverflow disallow enough tags to add more)   // using external c or binary is already how I cheat the need  as wrote in the first lines of the post

Comment: There isn't really a good solution to this as the terminal abstract does not have knowledge about the caps lock key and thus cannot toggle it.

Comment: Linux is the kernel, but multiple user-interface software packages can run on top of it.  For example the X Window system (typically the x.org implementation), or Wayland, or a text console terminal (with the kernel's own terminal emulation instead of xterm), or full-screen console applications like with SDL which I think get keyboard input via evdev or something like that, not a "terminal".

Comment: Also, unless the system hardware happens to be using a PS/2 keyboard (not USB),  an `out` instruction to port 0x60 isn't going to affect anything, even with `iopl` or `ioperm` to make it not segfault, or doing it via /dev/port.

Answer (score -1):

For today's need , in fact I can just change the logic of it all from why toupper with accept

```
'toupper' ( c1 -- c2 ) gforth-0.2 "toupper"
'accept' ( c-addr +n1 -- +n2  ) core "accept"
```

so I needed a capslock trigger but a better solution is to force convertion making a intermediary word to apply toupper over a `( addr len -- addr len )`

like calling toupper like

```
: >UPPER  ( addr len -- addr len)
  2DUP bounds do
    I C@ TOUPPER I C! \ convert each char in loop
  loop ; \ over the whole string
```

so I can use

```
pad dup 16 $INPUT >UPPER
```

without need to modify the capslock state neither the tty setup

therefore I am still interested in capslock trigger for future potential needs

Comment: This post does not answer to the initial question and is not related to it at all.

If you want to share this answer, it's better to create a corresponding question and post this answer to it.